# Passing $data variable to iframe from controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, iframe

I want to display a page in iframe. This page contains `email` contents since I am building an inbuilt email system. But the `CSS` of the email contents are overriding my `CSS` styles. Now this page gets some data from `$data` variable which I Pass through controller.

To avoid getting my `CSS` style issues I am thinking of displaying that page in an iframe. (**If anybody has any other solutions, welcome**).

```
inboxdetailspage.php --> View which displays email contents
mailactions.php  --> controller which passes $data to inboxdetailspage.php
```

This is the function that does it.

```
function viewInboxDetails(){
        $mailId            = $this->uri->segment('4');
        $data['emailInfo'] = $this->fetchParticularEmailInfo($mailId);
        $data['titleText'] = 'Email Information';


        $this->load->view('admin/inboxdetailspage',$data);

    }
```

I am absolutely blank on how to achieve this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data to the `IFRAME` from the same controller is not possible.
`IFRAMEs'` are just basically another URL display on a particular page. Hence all you can do is can pass the data via URL and thats it!
How this can be achieved this is create another (say) link for displaying the mail content by taking the ID from the URL and display that URL in iFrame. For example,

**Controller:**

```
public function all_mails()
{
    $data['mails'] = $this->xyz_model->get_mails();

    $this->load->view('all_mails.php', $data);
}

public function mail_content($mail_id)
{
    $data['mail'] = $this->xyz_model->get_mail_content($mail_id);

    $this->load->view('mail_content.php', $data);
}
```

**View:**

*all_mails.php*

```
<?php foreach($mails as $mail) { ?>

   <table>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $mail->from; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $mail->subject; ?></td>
           <!-- Your email content  -->
           <td>
               <iframe src="/xyz/mail_content/<?php echo $mail->id; ?>"></iframe>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>

<?php } ?>
```

*mail_content.php*

```
<!-- Your CSS here  -->
<link href="/static/home/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <div>
     <?php echo $mail->content;  ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass $data to your view and from there call another controller which can render your whole iframe from it with its own view.

Answer (score 0):

Create an iframe in the view linking to another function in controller(a new page). In this page display only email contents according to the email.